# Como pegar o valor do item selecionado no listbox?

Tags: vb.net

Dessa maneira que eu fiz eu não consegui, da Object reference not set to an instance of an object!

```
Private Sub btnDeletarPerfil_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeletarPerfil.Click

    Roles.DeleteRole(lbPerfis.SelectedItem.Value.ToString())

ou dessa maneira >>
    Roles.DeleteRole(lbPerfis.SelectedItem.Text.ToString())

End Sub
```

Comment: Uma dúvida bem boba, mas você está selecionado algo no seu lbPerfis?

Comment: Sim, estou o campo tem validação!

Answer (score 1):

No caso o item está selecionado, correto e é este ítem que quer excluir da listbox.

Então neste caso é mais interessante que utilize o índice do listbox para excluir

```
Private Sub btnDeletarPerfil_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeletarPerfil.Click

    lbPerfis.Items.RemoveAt(lbPerfis.SelectedItem.SelectedIndex)


End Sub
```